# Recommended way to get Activity inside Mortar screen?

Tags: android, mortar, square-flow

I am using Mortar and Flow to power my app. If I have the following View:

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {
  @Inject MyScreen.Presenter presenter;
  private EditText someText;

  public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Mortar.inject(context, this);
  }

  @Override protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    presenter.takeView(this);
  }

  @Override protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    presenter.dropView(this);
  }
 }
```

And the following screen:

```
@Layout(R.layout.my_view)
public class MyScreen implements Blueprint {
  @Override public String getMortarScopeName() {
    return getClass().getName();
  }

  @Override public Object getDaggerModule() {
    return new Module();
  }

  @dagger.Module(injects = MyView.class, addsTo = MyActivity.Module.class)
  public class Module {
  }

  @Singleton
  public class Presenter extends ViewPresenter<MyView> {
    private final SomeAsyncService service;

    @Inject
    Presenter() { }

    @Override public void onLoad(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    @Override public void onSave(Bundle outState) {
    }

  }
}
```

Now I would like to get access to Activity which is using this Screen and View. I would to have access to some of the Activity methods like:

```
getWindow()
finish()
getLayoutInflater()
getFragmentManager()

etc
```

I have tried to cast a Context like this inside my Screen:

```
Activity activity = (Activity)getView.getContext;
```

But this of course throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: mortar.MortarContextWrapper cannot be cast to 
android.app.Activity
```

How to get that activity? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not for sure, but Mortar is not recommended to use activity instance directly ?

[This mortal sample](https://github.com/square/mortar/blob/master/mortar-sample/src/main/java/com/example/mortar/android/ActionBarOwner.java) is helpful.
So, I implemented as follows.

```java
class WindowOwner extends Presenter<WindowOwner.Activity> {

    interface Activity {
        void addFragsToWindow(int flags);
    }

    public static class Config() {
        final private int flags;
        Config(int flags) { this.flags = flags; }
        public int getFlags() { return this.flags; }
    }

    private Config config;

    public void setConfig(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
        update();
    }

    private void update() {
         WindowOwner.Activity activity = getView();
         if (activity != null) {
              activity.addFlagsToWindow(config.getFlags());
         }
    }

    @dagger.Module(injects = {}, library = true)
    public static class WindowOwnerModule {
         @Provides
         @Singleton
         WindowOwner provideWindowOwnerPersenter() { return new WindowOwner(); }
    }
}
```

You define a `WindowOwner.Module` , and include of this class to your module like this.

```java
@Module(injects = {}, library = true)
public class AndroidModule {

    // WindowOwner provider
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SystemBarOwner provideWindowOwnerPersenter() {
        return new WindowOwner();
    } 
}
```

```java
@Module(
        includes = {
            AndroidModule.class, // Includes your modules
        },
        injects = {
               MainApplication.class
        },
        library = true
)
public final class MainModule {

    private final MainApplication mApplication;

    public MainModule(MainApplication application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }
}
```

And you implement Activivty like follows.

```java
 class AwesomeActivity extends Activity implements WindowOwner.Activity {
      @Inject WindowOwner windowOwner;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          Mortar.inject(this, this);
          this.windowOwner.takeView(this);
      }

      @Override
      void addFragsToWindow(int flags) {
          getWindow().addFlags(flags);
      }
 }
```

You can be used via WindowOwner

```
@Layout(R.layout.awesome_view)
public class AwesomeScreen implements Blueprint {

    @Override
    public String getMortarScopeName() {
        return getClass().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDaggerModule() {
        return new Module(getViewState());
    }

    @dagger.Module(
            injects = {
                    AwesomeView.class // inject your view
            },
            addsTo = MainModule.class,
            library = true
    )
    public static class Module {
    }

    @Singleton
    public static class Presenter extends ViewPresenter<AwesomeView> {

         private final WindowOwner windowOwner;

         @Inject
         Presenter(WindowOwner windowOwner) {
             this.windowOwner = systemBarOwner;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onEnterScope(MortarScope scope) {
             super.onEnterScope(scope);

             // Update window flags via WindowOwner.Config
             this.windowOwner.setConfig(new WindowOwner.Config(YOUR_FLAGS));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I think this example doesn't work. I am trying to make it work for last two days but it doesn't work. Can you provide a little bit more details?

Comment: @user4386126 OK, I added some sources.
hope your helpful.